# How to array result form postgres 9.5 using php 5.5.17 like JSON for Google chart

Tags: php, arrays, json, postgresql, google-visualization

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=bla"); 
$result = pg_query($db,"SELECT kv.ph, kv.broj FROM public.kv ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5"); 

while ($row = pg_fetch_object($result)) { 
    echo json_encode($row),','; 
} 

pg_close($db);
```

I get:

`{"ph":"6","broj":"4"},{"ph":"6","broj":"5"},{"ph":"7","broj":"6"},`

I need like this:

`'[[6, 4],[6, 5],[7,6]]'`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the [pg_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) function instead and construct an array of the data in the format that you want.

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=bla"); 
$result = pg_query($db,"SELECT kv.ph, kv.broj FROM public.kv ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5"); 

$return = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $return[] = array((int)$row[0],(int)$row[1]); 
} 

pg_close($db); 

var_dump($return);       
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

In JSON; {} denotes an object and a [] denotes an Array. Just for future reference.

Comment: What about "" in array?
[["6","4"],["6","5"],["7","6"],["9","8"],["5","9"]]

Comment: Do you need the " in your array? You can throw `(string)` in front of `$row[0]` and another in front of `$row[1]` to get the "".

Comment: I don't need ", it's number

Comment: You can cast to `(int)` to remove the "" if there are any.

Comment: something like ?
(array(int($row[0]),int$row[1]);

Answer (score 0):

```
$return = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $return[] = array((int)$row[0],(int)$row[1]);
} 

pg_close($db); 

//var_dump($return);       
echo json_encode($return);
```

This is answer, thanks too WillParky93.
If you need string (for dates) use

`STRING array((string)$row[0],(int)$row[1]);`